# How to localise WPF application so that right to left languages are displayed correctly?

Tags: .net, wpf, localization, internationalization, right-to-left

What steps are required to localise a WPF application so that right to left languages are displayed correctly?

Answer (score 2):

I realize its an old question but I am stuck with this as well so am adding what I've done (which works partially) in the hope that someone will add more to it

In your app.cs you can do something like this

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
          typeof(FrameworkElement),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));

        FrameworkElement.FlowDirectionProperty.OverrideMetadata(
        typeof(FrameworkElement),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft
                                      ? FlowDirection.RightToLeft : FlowDirection.LeftToRight));

    }
```

Now this flips everything all right but it also happens to flip all images which is not what you really want.

Comment: I had success by setting the FlowDirectionProperty for images back to LeftToRight: `FrameworkElement.FlowDirectionProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Image), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(FlowDirection.LeftToRight));`

Comment: This might be a solution, but it is incomplete since it brakes content inside DevExpress grid cells where English text characters are inverted. It might be a problem DX I have not tested with standard controls.

Answer (score 0):

For my use case adding below code in **MainWindow.cs** was enough:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Here
        this.FlowDirection =
            CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft ?
                FlowDirection.RightToLeft :
                FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
    }
```